# Debugging software that is launched by batch file (x64dbg)

Tags: debugging, reverse-engineering, disassembly

I've been getting in to reverse engineering a bit and have come across a piece of software that I'm unsure how to start on. The software is launched by a batch file (which also calls a second batch file) before it calls the executable. If I load the batch file in to x64dbg I get a PE file error which is expected. But I can't run the executable directly as I get a missing dll error. Any idea how I might get around this to get started? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Ollydbg instead as it seems to load batch files.

Answer (score 0):

For future references, you can copy the dll(s) to the directory the PE is in. Not sure what software this is, but the downside I can see is possibly running into dependency hell? You won't really know until your executable stops complaining about missing dll's.